# node.js max call stack exceeded error

Tags: javascript, node.js

### I am learning node and here is a simple emit recursion

```
var events = require('events'),timers = require('timers');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter,
       util = require('util');
//class initi
var myt = function() 
{
}
util.inherits(myt, EventEmitter);

myt.prototype.fnc = function(c) 
{
  console.log(c + ":send custom");this.emit('tick recv',c); 
 }

var Ticker = new myt();
Ticker.on('tick recv',function(c)  
{
  console.log(c + ':got custom');
})

Ticker.tick = function(c) 
{
Ticker.fnc(c);
timers.setTimeout(Ticker.tick(c+1), 100);
 }

 Ticker.tick(0);
```

---

I get "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error (and also the timeouts do not seem to be working"). There seems to be some basic error. Can anyone spot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `Ticker.tick()` unconditionally inside `Ticker.tick()`.  I think you mean:

```
Ticker.tick = function(c) 
{
  Ticker.fnc(c);
  timers.setTimeout(function() { Ticker.tick(c+1); }, 100);
}
```

The first argument to `setTimeout()` should be a function; in your code, you were passing the result of calling a function.

Comment: Thanks Pointy! That was it. Will accept the answer once SO allows.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a function to `setTimeout` and pass the function's arguments as the third, fourth, etc.. arguments of `setTimeout`, like so:

```
Ticker.tick = function(c) {
  Ticker.fnc(c);
  timers.setTimeout(Ticker.tick, 100, c+1);
}
```